# How do I dissolve sodium oleate in distilled water

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, temperature

I wanted to know how to dissolve sodium oleate powder in distilled water?  Does it have to be at a certain temp?  I need a 2% solution

Answer (score 1):

A [product information](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma/Product_Information_Sheet/2/o7501pis.pdf) by Sigma-Aldrich, a chemical supplier, cites Merck Index regarding the solubility of sodium oleate.  And states "It is 
also soluble in water (approximately 100 mg/ml)", in other words, 10 mass%.  Since this value is larger than the 2 mass% requested by you, and provided sodium oleate is a surfactant anyway, just go ahead.  A gentle warming, like 30 to 40 Celsius, may accelerate the process, though.